# Next.js | TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'secret')

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

I was trying to authenticate the API routes in next.js but getting the below error.
Page level Authentication is working fine. But wile trying to get the session in the API routes, getting error.

```
error - TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'secret')
at unstable_getServerSession (C:\Users\amond07\Workspace\Time_Management_App\time-management-matrix\time-management-matrix-web\node_modules\next-auth\next\index.js:78:48)
at __WEBPACK_DEFAULT_EXPORT__ (webpack-internal:///(api)/./pages/api/tasks/[user]/[date]/index.js:14:100)
at Object.apiResolver (C:\Users\amond07\Workspace\Time_Management_App\time-management-matrix\time-management-matrix-web\node_modules\next\dist\server\api-utils\node.js:179:15)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
at async DevServer.runApi (C:\Users\amond07\Workspace\Time_Management_App\time-management-matrix\time-management-matrix-web\node_modules\next\dist\server\next-server.js:381:9)
at async Object.fn (C:\Users\amond07\Workspace\Time_Management_App\time-management-matrix\time-management-matrix-web\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:500:37)
at async Router.execute (C:\Users\amond07\Workspace\Time_Management_App\time-management-matrix\time-management-matrix-web\node_modules\next\dist\server\router.js:213:36)
at async DevServer.run (C:\Users\amond07\Workspace\Time_Management_App\time-management-matrix\time-management-matrix-web\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:619:29)
at async DevServer.run (C:\Users\amond07\Workspace\Time_Management_App\time-management-matrix\time-management-matrix-web\node_modules\next\dist\server\dev\next-dev-server.js:536:20)
at async DevServer.handleRequest (C:\Users\amond07\Workspace\Time_Management_App\time-management-matrix\time-management-matrix-web\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:320:20)
```

**Below is the code snippets**

**pages/api/[...nextauth].js**

```
import GoogleProviders from "next-auth/providers/google";

export default NextAuth({
  // Configure one or more authentication providers
  providers: [
    GoogleProviders({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET,
    }),
    // ...add more providers here
  ],
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
});
```

**pages\tasks\[user]\date**

```
import clientPromise from "../../../../../lib/mongodb";
import { authOptions } from "../../../auth/[...nextauth]";
import { unstable_getServerSession } from "next-auth/next";

export default async (req, res) => {
  const { user, date } = req.query;
  const session = await unstable_getServerSession(req, res, authOptions);

  try {
    const client = await clientPromise;
    const db = client.db();
    const tasks = await db
      .collection("tasks")
      .find({ user: user, taskDate: date })
      .sort({ startDate: -1 })
      .toArray();

    res.status(200).send({ tasks });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).send({ error: "failed to fetch data" });
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issue.
Issue was the way I was exporting it.
The **unstable_getServerSession** accepts a json object as authOptions but I was providing a function.

Edited the **[...nextAuth].js** as below:

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import GoogleProviders from "next-auth/providers/google";
import { NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth";

export const authOptions = {
  // Configure one or more authentication providers
  providers: [
    GoogleProviders({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET,
    }),
    // ...add more providers here
  ],
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
};

export default NextAuth(authOptions);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the "NEXTAUTH_SECRET" (properly) defined in your .env?

Comment: Yes.
I am getting authOptions as undefined.

Comment: @Arindam no i mean if you have defined the variable "NEXTAUTH_SECRET" in your env where you store the data for your script (like "GOOGLE_SECRET")

Comment: @Jubewe Yes I have provided the secrets in the .env file.

NEXTAUTH_SECRET=MY_SECRET